# How to group messages per User in Swift - Firebase Backend

Tags: swift, firebase, chat

I use firebase as the database, when a message is sent by a sender to a receiver, The firebase database gets updated with the message.

The Message Data Contains the senderID, ReceiverID as well as the SenderName and TimeStamp and typeOfMedia being sent.

I want a way to send this message to the receiving end and group messages effectively

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a few messaging apps and had some success.  This is how I implemented my Firebase data structures.

For direct messages between users, I have an entry that looks like this:

```
direct-messages:
    user-A-UID:
        user-B-UID:
            message-1-ID:
                senderId: "user-A-UID",
                senderName: "User A",
                text: "hello, User B!",
                timestamp: 1490570058,
                status: "read"
            message-2-ID:
                senderId: "user-B-UID",
                senderName: "User B",
                text: "well hello, user A.  How are you?",
                timestamp: 1490570212,
                status: "sent"
    user-B-UID:
        user-A-UID:
            message-1-ID:
                senderId: "user-A-UID",
                senderName: "User A",
                text: "hello, User B!",
                timestamp: 1490570058,
                status: "read"
            message-2-ID:
                senderId: "user-B-UID",
                senderName: "User B",
                text: "well hello, user A.  How are you?",
                timestamp: 1490570212,
                status: "sent"
```

So what does this mean for your code?  Well, you can use an `.childAdded` listener on `ref.child("direct-messages").child(uid)` with `let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid`.

In your messaging UI, when the send button is pressed, do something like `let messageId = ref.child("direct-messages").child(uid).childByAutoId()`.  This will give you a unique identifier per message.  Use this like `ref.child("direct-messages").child(uid).child(messageId).updateChildValues(newMessagePacket)`

Now you don't want just anyone writing to this, so you also need to set up permissions accordingly.  `direct-messages.$uid` should only be able to be written to when `$uid == auth.uid`.  Check out [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) for some more detailed info on that.

But if user B is only listening to `direct-messages.user-B-UID` for new children, then how can they get updates when user A sends a message (which, based on the above permissions, is only written to `direct-messages.user-A-UID.$messageID`)?  Well the best way to do this is to use a small Amazon EC2 instance running node to listen for updates using the firebase-admin library, and duplicate the data over to `direct-messages.user-B-UID.$messageID`.

---

This is more or less the technique I use in 2 production messaging apps.  I feel like the key to Firebase is data duplication, and permissions.  This has worked well for me, but let me know if you've got any more questions.